# How to trigger beta review with Fastlane?

Tags: testflight, fastlane

Here is my `upload_to_testflight` (aka `pilot`) configuration which supposed to send a build to external testers. It *does* upload build to TestFlight and "adds" a build to a group of external testers. However, it does not trigger a review and testers never get invitations.

```rb
upload_to_testflight(
    beta_app_feedback_email: "redacted",
    beta_app_description: "redacted",
    demo_account_required: true,
    distribute_external: true,
    groups: ["MyGroup"],
    changelog: "MyApp version #{VERSION} build #{BUILD}",
    beta_app_review_info: {
        contact_email: "redacted",
        contact_first_name: "redacted",
        contact_last_name: "redacted",
        contact_phone: "redacted",
        demo_account_name: "redacted",
        demo_account_password: "redacted",
    },
)
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is it even possible to trigger beta app review with Fastlane?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: I no longer work on this particular project, so I have no idea ‍♂️

Comment: Supposedly this is addressed, according to this ticket https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16294

Comment: can I leave the `demo_account` keys in `beta_app_review_info` out if I set `demo_account_required: false`?